# Write Batch variables to the filename

Tags: variables, batch-file, filenames

i have a problem with batch and i can´t find the answer. I want to write a variable into the name of a file, that will be created. :) I want to make a Joomla Helper Batch. It should generate a grid for Modules. It is only for my purposes. 
This is my example code.

`@echo off
set /pmodulename = Please insert the name of the Module:
echo ^<?xml version^=^'1.0^' encoding^=^'utf-8^' ?^> ^<extension type^=^'module^' version^=^'3.0^' client^=^'site^' method^=^'upgrade^'^> > "%modulename%".xml`

After executing the batch file, there is a xml file, but it has no name. So how can i append the variable name to the file?

Greetings 
Kevin Grahn

Comment: `set /p "modulename=Please insert the name of the Module: "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that you have a space before the = remove that and it should be fine

Before:

```
set /pmodulename = Please insert the name of the Module:
```

After:

```
set /pmodulename= Please insert the name of the Module:
```

Just run your line in a cmd window then run set to see the list you will see the variable has the space.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. :)